# Why would std::copy not vectorize?

Tags: c++, vectorization

Consider this general code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy    

int main() {
    const int n=1024;
    float a1[n],a2[n];
    std::srand(std::time(0)); 
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)      a2[i]=std::rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    std::copy(a2,a2+n,a1);
}
```

when I compile this with `g++/gcc 4.8.1` and the `-O3 -march=native -mtune=native` flag on Ubuntu, I get that the line corresponding to the copy can't be vectored because:

```
note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
```

If I use

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)      a1[i]=a2[i];
```

I also get the same compiler message. I'm a bit puzzled. Intuitively I would think 
a copy between two non-overlapping array must be eminently vector-able. Can 
anyone explain why this is not the case (and eventually provide a fix, though 
admittedly this is not a bottleneck in my code, I'm mostly asking for the sake of understanding what that error message mean).

Comment: Your code is too broken and incomplete to reproduce the result. Please update it to something that can actually be compiled.

Comment: @larsmans: OK: I do now (sorry I wanted to keep it short). Is it better now?

Comment: std::copy returns an iterator to the end of the destination range. So you will need something to iterate over. If you a1 would be a vector (`std::vector<float> a1(n);`) it is all fine isn't it or am I missing the question...

Comment: What if you use memmove()?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: same compiler message.

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57579 It seems that your code is fine and it is just an "information" message.

Comment: @MP24: Fantastic: thanks!. Can you post this an an answer? I would gladly accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your code is fine and it is just an "information" message: See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57579. There, similar code will be vectorized by another method, and therefore the second vectorizing code spits out the informational message that it cannot vectorize (again).

Comment: Thanks! This solves part of the mystery. However, while I can see how that would happen with the std::copy function, it's not obvious to me what would that happen when doing 'for(int i=0;i<n;i++)      a1[i]=a2[i];'.

Comment: Did you have a look at the generated ASM code? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937003/why-does-vectorization-fail It contains the ASM output which shows that vectorized calls are used. You may want to compare the `std::copy` and manual copy ASM output.