# Why does vectorization fail?

Tags: c++, vectorization

I want to optimize my code for vectorization using

```
-msse2 -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2.
```

I have the following simple code:

```
int main(){
  int a[2048], b[2048], c[2048];
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<2048; i++){
      b[i]=0;
      c[i]=0;
  }

  for (i=0; i<2048; i++){
    a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Why do I get the note

```
 test.cpp:10: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you replace addition with two multiplications and one addition?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but I tried a[i]=b[i]*c[i]+d[i]*e[i] without any result...

Comment: This code has undefined behaviour, since you are reading from uninitialized variables.

Comment: @KerrekSB Initializing resulted in the same message, so I kept away this part, but will add it back.

Comment: To zero out why don't just use `memset`? It'll be much faster. What you should care is the vectorization on line 10

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc That is what he cares about, he just forgot to update the compiler output after he added the first loop.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Because `memset` has no place in C++. Use `= {0}` here, `std::fill` otherwise.

Comment: @Malloc the question has been edited. It's line 5 before

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc So was the interesting loop before. :)

Comment: Seems to compile without warnings on gcc 4.7 and [4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b646b0614a810093). What compiler are you using?

Comment: I know now, the first version didn't have initializations so line 5 fell to what is line 10 now, then he added the initilization but didn't change the line number

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: The question is asking how to get the compiler to automatically vectorise loops like these.  It's not asking for `memset` or `std::fill` or anything else.

Comment: @tmyklebu That's because previously he asked about vectorizing **on the initializing line**, not the adding line. After that he edited the code again

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Yeah, I can see the edits.  His original question was plenty clear.  Edit 5, which is the only one you could be talking about, is still a legitimate question whose answer isn't "use memset instead", and it's the only one with that error.

Comment: @tmyklebu Yes but at that time I didn't see the previous edits

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Sure.  My point is that the answer to "why isn't this memset-equivalent turning into a fast memset?" is not "use memset instead."  (Don't take this personally; people answering technical questions like this one with "don't reinvent the wheel" or "this thing that already exists will do a way better job" is a major pet peeve of mine.  Because, well, delving into what's going on in nontrivial examples is really gross.)

Comment: @repptilia Do you remember which compiler were you using? BTW: Note that tree-vectorizer-verbose is now obsolete, and should be replaced with, for example, -fopt-info-vec-missed-optimized See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-fopt-info-818

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, after adding an `asm volatile("": "+m"(a), "+m"(b), "+m"(c)::"memory");` near the end of `main`, my copy of `gcc` emits this:

```
400610:       48 81 ec 08 60 00 00    sub    $0x6008,%rsp
400617:       ba 00 20 00 00          mov    $0x2000,%edx
40061c:       31 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
40061e:       48 8d bc 24 00 20 00    lea    0x2000(%rsp),%rdi
400625:       00
400626:       e8 b5 ff ff ff          callq  4005e0 <memset@plt>
40062b:       ba 00 20 00 00          mov    $0x2000,%edx
400630:       31 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
400632:       48 8d bc 24 00 40 00    lea    0x4000(%rsp),%rdi
400639:       00
40063a:       e8 a1 ff ff ff          callq  4005e0 <memset@plt>
40063f:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
400641:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
400648:       c5 f9 6f 84 04 00 20    vmovdqa 0x2000(%rsp,%rax,1),%xmm0
40064f:       00 00
400651:       c5 f9 fe 84 04 00 40    vpaddd 0x4000(%rsp,%rax,1),%xmm0,%xmm0
400658:       00 00
40065a:       c5 f8 29 04 04          vmovaps %xmm0,(%rsp,%rax,1)
40065f:       48 83 c0 10             add    $0x10,%rax
400663:       48 3d 00 20 00 00       cmp    $0x2000,%rax
400669:       75 dd                   jne    400648 <main+0x38>
```

So it recognised that the first loop was just doing `memset` to a couple arrays and the second loop was doing a vector addition, which it appropriately vectorised.

I'm using `gcc version 4.9.0 20140521 (prerelease) (GCC)`.

An older machine with `gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)` also vectorises the loop, but in a different way.  Your `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2` setting makes it emit the following output:

```
Analyzing loop at foo155.cc:10


Vectorizing loop at foo155.cc:10

10: LOOP VECTORIZED.
foo155.cc:1: note: vectorized 1 loops in function.
```

You probably goofed your compiler flags (I used `g++ -O3 -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2 -march=native foo155.cc -o foo155` to build) or have a really old compiler.

Answer (score -2):

remove the first loop and do this

int a[2048], b[2048], c[2048] = {0};

also try this tag

```
-ftree-vectorize
```

instead of

```
-msse2 -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2
```

Comment: -ftree-vectorize is part of -03. If you do not enable sse up to some level (Note: for X86 architectures), you won't get any vectorization.